# Prove that $\forall g \in G$ $ \exists$ an irreducible non-trivial character $\chi$ of the group $G$ such that $\chi(g)\neq 0$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

> Let $G$ be a non-trivial  finite group. Prove that $\forall g \in G$  $ \exists$  an irreducible non-trivial character $\chi$ of the group $G$ such that $\chi(g)\neq 0$

This is my attempt so far.

Let us suppose for a contradiction that $ \exists g \in G$ such that for all non-trivial $\chi\in Irr(G)$  we have $\chi(g)=0.$

At this point I am now stuck. I assume that this has something to do with the orthogonality relations but I am unsure how to proceed.

Am I on the right path?

Thank you.

Comment: This character is a multiplicative functional right?

Comment: Isn't a character a homomorphism $\chi\colon G\to\mathbb C^\times$? And isn't $0\notin\mathbb C^\times$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: See here for a definition: [character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory).

Comment: @Hagen: for non-abelian groups, homomorphisms to $\mathbb C^{\times}$ are not enough.  Indeed, they kill all commutators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Simply use the column orthogonality relations: the dot product of your column (which contains only zeros and a single $1$) with any other column in the character table (for example the one belonging to $1$) should be zero, which leads immeadiately to a contradiction.

Comment: Another way of saying it, $\sum \chi(g) = 1$ means $g=1$ and $|G|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to look at the regular representation. $g \ne e$ has trace zero on this, but there is a copy of the trivial representation given by the sum of all the group elements which we can quotient by to get a representation where $g$ has character $-1$.